# Why I am getting LoadError for require 'support/number_helper' in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I am using the `require_relative 'support/number_helper'` it's working fine, But when I am using `require 'support/number_helper'` then I am getting this error.

```
rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./support/number_helper (LoadError)
```

I also tried this but getting the same error.

```
require './support/number_helper
```

I am using the ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

`require_relative 'support/number_helper'` searches for a file to load by adding given string to the directory of current_file (`__FILE__`). For example, in your project folder you have 2 files:

```
lib/special_gem/fetcher.rb
lib/special_gem/support/number_helper.rb
```

You can use `require_relative 'support/number_helper'` in your 1st file to load the 2nd. The command takes the path to the directory of the current file (`lib/special_gem/`), appends given string (`support/number_helper`) and successfully finds file to load.

What about `require` command, if given path is not absolute, it will search for the file in the directories listed in $LOAD_PATH. Very likely your `lib` folder is in this list, so to load 2nd file you could use the command

```
require 'special_gem/support/number_helper'
```

Since it's not relative, you can use it from your 1st file or **any other file of your project**.

When using `require 'support/number_helper'` it will search for the file at `lib/support/number_helper`. If that file is missing, `LoadError` exception is raised.

See [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require) for details.